# 'cout' was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, iostream, cout

I have a C++ program:

**test.cpp**

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    char t = 'f';
    char *t1;
    char **t2;
    cout<<t;    //this causes an error, cout was not declared in this scope
    return 0;
}
```

I get the **error**:

> 'cout' was not declared in this scope

Why?

Comment: I'm wondering how many times this got asked here.

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed as "too localized"?

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Put the following code before `int main()`:

```
using namespace std;
```

And you will be able to use `cout`.

For example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    char t = 'f';
    char *t1;
    char **t2;
    cout<<t;        
    return 0;
}
```

Now take a moment and read up on what cout is and what is going on here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/

---

Further, while its quick to do and it works, this is not exactly a good advice to simply add `using namespace std;` at the top of your code. For detailed correct approach, please read the answers to this [related SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1835769).

Comment: Such [bad advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice).

Comment: I know, I made that answer 2 years ago, but now I know it is good enough for beginner, because it is stupid and hard to explain novice programmer what namespace is.

Comment: I disagree. This is particularly bad for beginners because they can't see the implications.

Comment: I agree with @juanchopanza here. It is much easier to start with a solid foundation and explain what everything does so that they don't have to relearn the concepts of something that they thought they already have taken care of

Comment: tl;dr "using std::cout;"

Answer (score 45):

Use `std::cout`, since `cout` is defined within the `std` namespace. Alternatively, add a `using std::cout;` directive.